# Swift / Firestore setData with multiple documents at once causes app to crash

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a fitness app where you can favorite trainer accounts and when you favorite a trainer account I want to add all workouts posted by that trainer to the current user's feed.

**When you favorite a trainer account I use this function to add the workouts to a collection on firestore:**

```
func addToUserFeed() {
    guard let trainerUid = trainer.id else { return }
    guard let currentUid = AuthViewModel.shared.userSession?.uid else { return }

    COLLECTION_WORKOUTS.whereField("ownerUid", isEqualTo: trainerUid).addSnapshotListener { snapshot, _ in
        
        guard let workoutIDs = snapshot?.documents.map({ $0.documentID }) else { return }
        
        workoutIDs.forEach { id in
            COLLECTION_USERS.document(currentUid).collection("user-feed").document(id).setData([:])
        }

    }
}
```

**Similarly, when you unfavorite a trainer I am removing those workouts from the user feed collection with this function:**

```
func removeFromUserFeed() {
    guard let trainerUid = trainer.id else { return }
    guard let currentUid = AuthViewModel.shared.userSession?.uid else { return }

    COLLECTION_WORKOUTS.whereField("ownerUid", isEqualTo: trainerUid).addSnapshotListener { snapshot, _ in
        
        guard let workoutIDs = snapshot?.documents.map({ $0.documentID }) else { return }
        
        workoutIDs.forEach { id in
            COLLECTION_USERS.document(currentUid).collection("user-feed").document(id).delete()
        }

    }
}
```

**Then to display these workouts on the feed page view in my app I fetch all the workouts in the user-feed collection on firestore with this function:**

```
//FETCH WORKOUTS SAVED BY THE USER
func fetchFavoriteWorkouts() {

    guard let currentUid = AuthViewModel.shared.userSession?.uid else { return }

    COLLECTION_USERS.document(currentUid).collection("user-feed").addSnapshotListener { snapshot, _ in
        guard let workoutIDs = snapshot?.documents.map({ $0.documentID }) else { return }
        
        //THIS MAY CAUSE AN UNNECCESSARY AMOUNT OF WRITES TO THE APP
        self.workouts.removeAll()

        workoutIDs.forEach { id in
            COLLECTION_WORKOUTS.document(id).addSnapshotListener { snapshot, _ in
                guard let workout = try? snapshot?.data(as: Workout.self) else { return }
                self.workouts.append(workout)
                print("\(workoutIDs)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**This is what the firestore collection looks like for user-feed. It adds workout ID documents to the collection that match up with workouts posting by the trainer you just favorited:**

[Firestore structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqjSK.png)

This is working properly in a sense that when you favorite a trainer account it correctly adds multiple documents to the user-feed collection which correspond to workout IDs posted by the trainer you just favorited, however, when you favorite a trainer account the app just closes (not really crashes), and then when you re-open the app the user-feed correctly displays the workouts from trainers you have favorited.

Is there anything in my code that may be causing this random app close when you favorite a trainer?

I understand that this code may not be the most efficient, but I am really not focused on fixing that at the moment, just want to fix the random app close out.

**Edit:**
The crash only happens when I favorite a trainer that has multiple workouts posted. So I guess something causes the crash when I add multiple documents to a collection at once? Because if I favorite a trainer that only has one workout then it adds that workout to my feed without crashing at all.

Comment: What does the crash log say?

Comment: @jnpdx it is not actually a crash that registers in xcode. The app just closes. It happens if I favorite a trainer > than 1 workout. If I favorite a trainer with 3 workouts, it appears to be adding 3 different arrays or something like that, and each time adding the next workout. 

This is what the log looks like when I add a print statement to fetch workoutIDs from the saved trainer with 3 workouts:

WORKOUTIDS: ["dlrAHIpuwz9oz9rsDpvL"]
WORKOUTIDS: ["dlrAHIpuwz9oz9rsDpvL", "nJ3aR0bKB08rgCODepJK"]
WORKOUTIDS: ["dlrAHIpuwz9oz9rsDpvL", "nJ3aR0bKB08rgCODepJK", "y5ATrD20m4iolEYi563y"]

Comment: I’m not aware of a way that the app can just close without crashing. Have you replicated it while it is hooked up to the debugger?

Comment: @jnpdx so after rerunning it a different way, the error is "Fatal error: each layout item may only occur once".... So based on that log in my first comment, it appears when I favorite a trainer with more than 1 workout it is basically adding 3 separate arrays of workoutIDS -> [workout1id], [workout1id, workout2id], [workout1id, workout2id, workout3id]...

Comment: Unfortunately, the code that you've included is not enough to debug that issue. Ideally, you'd include a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is caused by the listener getting called each time a workout is added to workout list and adding duplicated values to the list .

change addSnapshotListener to getDocuments fetchFavoriteWorkouts()
and call this fetch function inside .onAppear() in feed View